# Calculate exponential growth using decimals

Tags: solidity, math

Is there any way to calculate the following in Solidity?

`468750 * 2.718281828459045 ** (x * 0.003662040962) - 468750`

Typically I would convert the decimals using `decimal * 10 ** 18` but with the exponent that will result in overflow.